# Center File Input - Html/Css

Tags: javascript, html, css

So guys, I am building a website using HTML, Javascript and CSS, and I have a file input but for some reason it won't get completely centered.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#inp {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: From this part of code we cannot say what is wrong if you have something more that may interrupt this but in your sample code you should put the styles in head section or at least before this input

Comment: work is fine what is issue ??

Comment: give width to #inp like 174px

Comment: see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49agf4h5/

Comment: I think the issue is the width of the input. If you select it, and see the blue highlight, it shows you that it is wider than the text and button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine, can we get the entire code ?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#inp {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input id="inp" type="file" accept="image/*">
</body>
```

Comment: This still doesn't look exactly centered.

Comment: change `text-align: center;` to `text-align-last: center;` and it will be more centered.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS solution for most recents browsers**

More detail on browsers support : http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

CSS3 introduced `vw, vh` units that take advantage of visible screen size. Here is an example showing how you might use those value to set `width` and `height` properties of your div to `100vw` (which means 100% of the Visible Width of the screen) and `100vh` (which means 100% of the Visible Height of the screen) :

```css
body {
  margin : 0px;
}

.fullscreen {
  width : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
}

.table-cell {
  display : table-cell;
  background : lightgrey;
}

.valign-middle {
  vertical-align : middle;
}

.text-center {
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen table-cell valign-middle text-center">
  <input type="file" />
</div>
```

Comment: This still doesn't look exactly centered.

Comment: Probably because that dumb text is throwing it off.  I'm sure the button and the text together as a single piece is centered.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to achieve this, but take a look at this 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cy90xeze/7/)

```
   #inp {
     text-align: center;
     margin: auto;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%; 
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

You can center the input file by enclosing it in a

tag and then adding CSS to it.